# Dockerfile issues with build

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to compose my own docker container,
my first issue is to gather the basic infrastructure - however docker build throw errors.

This is my file :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | -E bash - \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
```

This is the error while building :

```
et:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [20.2 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [170 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [1335 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources [5335 B]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources [7926 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages [1743 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages [16.0 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [7589 kB]
Fetched 21.8 MB in 23s (918 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
/bin/sh: 1: RUN: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && RUN apt-get install -y     git     curl' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Later on when I solve this issue I would like to clone my private bitbucket repository.

Thanks :)

Comment: Found out that I got 2 "RUN" in my second line, fixed that - yet I still get the PGP key issue.

Comment: edit your post to include that change please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get install -y ca-certificates
```

You are missing the base certs for https functionality.